# When should I call the componentWillUnmount() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I would like to Unmount my component and then mount again at certain time.to do that i am assigning a new key to component.

```
 <div>
 <Game key = {this.state.gameId} 
 createNewGame = {this.createNewGame.bind(this)} 
 rows = {5} 
 columns = {5} 
 activeCellsCount = {6} />;
 </div>
```

I have some timers to clear which i placed them in componentWillUnmount() as follows,

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("I am in Component will Unmount");
    clearTimeOut( this.memorizeTimerId );
    clearTimeOut( this.recallTimerId ); 
    this.finishGame();
}
```

When i am trying to do Unmount and mount, Getting error inside componentWillUnmount() as "Uncaught ReferenceError: clearTimeOut is not defined" by indicating both clearTimeOut() methods. componentWillUnmount() is placed inside 'Game' component. is anything wrong with this method?

Comment: the 'O' in `clearTimeout` is not upper case.

Comment: @Mukesh Soni--Thank you. Error is cleared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code.

```
clearTimeOut( this.memorizeTimerId );
```

Change this to

```
clearTimeout( this.memorizeTimerId );
```

It works fine, I have tried it.

Comment: It's been already resolved by @Mukesh Soni. Any way thank you for your suggestion.